# Android Volley "Unknown Host Exception" when tried to fetch IPV6 address

Tags: android, android-volley, ipv6

Im trying to get IPV6 public address via volley.

So far, i managed to toast ip address for IPV4 but when volley tries to fetch IPV6 data, it throws **Unknown Host Exception** even the code for both method were same except the url part..

What happen? I already give internet permission in manifest.

My implementation were as below:

**Service file**

```
 @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent pIntent, int flags, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(this, "Restart service!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        PublicIPResolver.getIPV4(GooglePlayService.this, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
           public void onResponse(String s) {
               Toast.makeText(GooglePlayService.this,s,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
           }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
               @Override
               public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                   Toast.makeText(GooglePlayService.this,volleyError.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
           });

        PublicIPResolver.getIPV6(GooglePlayService.this, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String r) {
                Toast.makeText(GooglePlayService.this,r,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                Toast.makeText(GooglePlayService.this,volleyError.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


        return super.onStartCommand(pIntent, flags, startId);
    }
```

**PublicIPResolver class**

```
public class PublicIPResolver {

    public static void getIPV4(Context context, Response.Listener<String> ip, Response.ErrorListener errorListener)
    {
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        String url ="http://v4.ipv6-test.com/api/myip.php";
        // Request a string response from the provided URL.
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, ip,errorListener);
        // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    public static void getIPV6(Context context, Response.Listener<String> ip, Response.ErrorListener errorListener)
    {
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        String url ="http://v6.ipv6-test.com/api/myip.php";
        // Request a string response from the provided URL.
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, ip,errorListener);
        // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try opening your url in device's browser to check if it is accessible from the device or not

Comment: Oh....its not accessible...Thanks for the clue...Wierd as i can access it as usual in normal browser. Is IPv6 not supported?

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3718/does-android-have-support-for-ipv6

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Does-Android-support-IPv6

Comment: Oh....thanks for the clue! btw In my cases,  It turns out that my emulator is the only one Which cant access it. I tried to use it on my real device and its work fine. Thanks a lot!